# Fast and easy way to get formula of circuit?

Tags: digital-logic

[image]

[image]

What would be a fast and easy way to solve problems like these? I seem to get a lot like these in my course.

Also the other way around; Questions like: How many NAND gates are at least needed for a particular formula?

Comment: You can use algebraic methods to reduce expressions.   If you have a truth table, a Karnaugh map is a means of deriving a minimal expression, it would be somewhat surprising if both had not been covered in your lectures.  Note that in the real world minimal expressions are not always what is most desirable at implementation level.

Comment: @ChrisStratton K-maps were indeed covered. But making these would take some time, and I am looking for a way to just scan through the circuit and find the matching formula, or find formula's that definitely can't match.

Comment: There are some shorthand tricks. Here's one. Count the inversion bubbles on one input (W is a good choice here because it's relatively simple) and trace it through the internal paths. Now you know whether W appears normal, inverted, both, or neither - and in this case you can eliminate 2 of the choices in seconds.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thanks, this is the kind of answer I was looking for. How exactly would I have to trace W through the internal parts? And after that, I would still have two options, so what are other tricks to find the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multiple choice questions you can use process of elimination by checking for mismatches with an equation's sub-expressions. For sum of products ( e.g.: \$( a \cdot b ) + ( c \cdot d ) + \dots \$ ) when the sub-expression is one, then the diagram must also be one to be a possible match. For product of sums ( e.g.: \$( a + b ) \cdot ( c + d ) \cdot \dots \$ ) when a sub-expression is zero, then the diagram must also be zero to be a possible match.

For example a sum of products with a sub-expression \$ x \cdot \bar{y} \$. Evaluate the diagram with \$x\$ as one, \$y\$ as zero, and X(unknown) for all other inputs. Is \$S\$ guaranteed to be equal to **one**? If false, then the total expression is false.

Another example of a product of sums with a sub-expression \$(\bar{y}+z)\$. Evaluate the diagram with \$y\$ as one, \$z\$ as zero, and X(unknown) for all other inputs. Is \$S\$ guaranteed to be equal to **zero**? If false, then the total expression is false.

To speed things up, check the first sub-expression of each equation before evaluating any of the other sub-expressions in the same equation. A false will eliminate the equation for the list of possibilities, but it does not guaranty the total expression is correct.

Worst case is there is a "non of the above" option or two or more options remain. In this case for the remaining possible expressions you can try converting sum of products to product of sums, vice-versa, then re-evaluate for false. Or make and compare true tables or k-maps. Which ever you feel more convertible with.

> How many NAND gates are at least needed for a particular formula?

After reduction, convert the formula into sum of products if it is not already (there is another approach for product of sums, but I'm skipping for you to figure out). You will need one NAND gate for each product, plus one NAND gate for the sum, and a NAND gate for each unique inversion. This is understood by the equivalency expressions \$ a \cdot b + c \cdot d \equiv \overline{(\overline{a \cdot b}) \cdot (\overline{c \cdot d})}\$ and \$\overline{a} \equiv \overline{a \cdot a}\$. It is complicated if there is a restriction to use only 2 input NAND gates, but the concept is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I use DeMorgan's rules in my head and convert NAND to OR

- and invert all inputs and output to see that you have 3 OR terms then examine the polarity of S for each input x,y,z,w
- starting  with the unique term, w after 4 inversions, that  rule out answers a,d which have w!
- then with x,y having 3&4 inversions and both having the same logic towards S, rule out b,

  - > leaving c to be the only answer left and prove it is the same.